# [ROS2] Is it possible to listen and subscribe to newly created topic in C++?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if it's possible programmatically.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330277/%5Bros2%5D-is-it-possible-to-listen-and-subscribe-to-newly-created-topic-in-c++?/) by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2019-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can dynamically create new subscriptions in c++ at run time.

Use the `create_subscription` method on Node

http://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp/index.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-08-08**:
How about discovering new topics that are created during run time?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-08-08**:
Sure. You can get the list of topics and their types that have been discovered at any time from the API.

See http://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp/index.html (search for “introspecting the ROS graph”)

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-08-08**:
But if type is not known in advance, how can we create the subscription? As the message type is needed at the time of subscription creation.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-08-08**:
Use the api linked above in the comment to get the list of topics and their types before you call create subscription. Or know through some other means what type you're expecting. The callback must match the type too so you're going to need to have an idea about the type beforehand anyway.

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-08-08**:
Got it. Thanks!